# Using multiple GitHub instances with different email addresses

Tags: git, github

Suppose I have a local git repository to share.  All commits belong to (alice, alice@example.com) to share on github.enterprise.example.com.  I have an account (username, username@users.noreply.github.com) on github.com and decided to share the repository globally on github.com too.

How can I achieve this?  The trivial solution is to have another local repository for publishing to github.com, sync the content manually or with other tools, and commit and push separately.  Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: You still want the commits to belong to alice@example.com for the github.com repo, correct?

Comment: No.  Suppose that I want to be anonymous on github.com.

Comment: But your commits are tagged with the specific author in the enterprise account. So if you're trying to do a true sync via a `git push` the authors for those commits on GitHub.com is the same. Keep in mind that the commit hash is dependent on a number of things, including the author information (name, email address, GitHub account).

Comment: Yes, I.'d like the same history (branches with source code, commit messages and dates) with replaced author information.

Comment: Why is the original repo private while this one is public? Private repositories are private for a reason and making the code publicly available poses several legal issues.

Comment: There can be a situation that a company does not allow publishing a specific software as the company (because  of, for example, low quality), but allows making the code itself (and history without company identity) public.

Answer (score 0):

Git has the concept of [*remotes*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes). A single repository can have configured as many remotes as you need. When you clone a repository, a single default remote is already setup with the name `origin`.

For example, if you have your local repository and want to push it to the company server and to GitHub, add both of them as separate remotes:

```
git remote add office git@github.enterprise.example.com/path/to/repo
git remote add github git@github.com/user/project.git
```

You can now fetch from either of them:

```
git fetch office
git fetch github
```

Or to fetch all at once:

```
git fetch --all
```

To push branches, do as you would with `origin`, but specify the appropriate remote:

```
git push office mybranch
git push github anotherbranch
```